# How would I go about rebuilding an object in an Oracle XE database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I need to rebuild the following object in an Oracle database...can somebody tell me how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

OBJECT ID = 576

OBJECT_NAME

OBJECT_TYPE

SMON_SCN_TIME_TIM_IDX
INDEX

Comment: Who's the owner of that object?  SYS?

Comment: I have just put an answer on your OTN thread.  I suggest you post to the OTN XE forum and get some expert advice.

Comment: I fixed the problem without taking the database down by dropping and recreating the index using:

drop index smon_scn_time_scn_idx;
drop index smon_scn_time_tim_idx;
create unique index smon_scn_time_scn_idx on smon_scn_time(scn);
create unique index smon_scn_time_tim_idx on smon_scn_time(time_mp);
analyze table smon_scn_time validate structure cascade;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect as SYS (or equivalent privileges) and do this:

```
alter index smon_scn_time_tim_idx rebuild;
```

Comment: Will this affect anything else?

Thanks for your help...as a sys admin I'm not very well versed in a lot of the DBA sorta things.

Comment: @user294746 - SMON is an Oracle background process (System MONitor)so anything do with it has the potential to impact everything else.

Comment: Rebuilding an index will not invalidate other objects.  I should have asked - why are you rebuilding it - is it marked as INVALID?

Answer (score 0):

What's your scope for downtime on the database ?

Playing with any SYSTEM / SYS object (especially on an unsupported database like XE) is dangerous.

Since XE is limited to 4GB in volume, I'd consider taking the DB offline / export / fresh install / import as a solution.

Comment: I fixed the problem by dropping and recreating the indexes using the following:


drop index smon_scn_time_scn_idx;
drop index smon_scn_time_tim_idx;
create unique index smon_scn_time_scn_idx on smon_scn_time(scn);
create unique index smon_scn_time_tim_idx on smon_scn_time(time_mp);
analyze table smon_scn_time validate structure cascade;